Firefox bookmarks folders don't open on hover
I posted this question long ago on Mozilla's own forum, but didn't receive a definitive answer, so let's try on a higher-traffic forum.
I've got plenty of bookmarks organized in folders and sub-folders (never could wrap my head around using tags). I use Firefox 115.11 ESR on Mac OS X 10.14, but this bug has been lingering for the past two years.
Normally, hovering on top of a folder or sub-folder just expands it. However for some unknown reason, some folders just don't show their content on hovering. There's no apparent pattern in the failure.
By contrast, opening the "Manage bookmarks" pane shows all bookmarks are there and functional. The issue only appears in the bookmarks menu, and I'm not sure when it appeared exactly.
Already tried:
Checked favicons.sqlite and places.sqlite using about:support special page: both reported as sane
Tested on Windows: no bug
Tested on Linux Mint: BUG!
Tested in another profile: BUG!
Renaming faulty folders: no effect
Moving bookmarks into a newly created folder:  no effect
Moving faulty folders into an already-working folder: works, except if the folder is the one containing the root menu.
An update: I went through the tedious job of re-creating all the main folders by hand, sorted out the bookmarks and removed the ones that were dead but wouldn't give a proper 404. To my surprise, on some of those newly-created folders and re-added bookmarks (not moved), the same issue appeared!
Or so it seems…

Expected behaviour:

When one clicks the "Bookmarks" menu, menu expands down. Sub-menu expand rights (monitor real estate permitting), then the next sub-menu expands left so as to keep everything visible. I'd expect the next sub-menu to open right again, but don't currently have so many sub-levels.

Wrong behaviour:

Main menu opens down, expands right, then right again. Of course, since there's no more monitor space to display the menu, it's badly squeezed to the point of being irrelevant (circled in green at the far right. Note the menu doesn't spill on the other monitor in Mac OS X).
When I abbreviate some links titles in the "ByT" menu to reduce its overall width, the sub-menus are indeed properly displayed:

What I still don't understand is that sub-menus too wide to fit are in fact correctly shortened by Firefox…

An update: I recently went through the very tedious process of removing and adding my bookmarks in folders I recreated. This helped me getting rid of outdated bookmarks that regular plugins couldn't see (domain parking, "/lander" blank pages, not proper 404s).
However, some newly created folders starting displaying the same issue!
